# Issue calculating angle

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, geometry, angle

I have the following data:

Notice the scale of the data is really small. What I need to do is calculate the angle between each point and the positive y axis, and then do this again but find the angle to the positive x axis. I think of the positive y axis as the vector stretching from the origin to the point (0,1), and the positive x-axis being the vector starting at the origin to the point (1,0). Here is what I've done so far:
[image: First]

```
 for i=1:length(X)
  angles(i)=acos(dot([0,1],X(i,:))/sqrt(dot([0,1],[0,1])*dot(X(i,:),X(i,:)))).*180/pi;
  angles_2(i)=atan2d(X(i,1),X(i,2)).*180/pi;
end
```

X represents the data vector, where the first column is the x-coordinates, and the second column is the respective y coordinates. angles and angles_2 show 2 different ways I tried to calculate the angles to the positive y-axis. They both gave me the same answer, but I'm really not sure if this is right. I tested these methods on another data set:
[image: Second]

You can clearly see that the first point (not on the origin) on the second data set is much further away from y axis than the first point from the first data set. Therefore, I should get a bigger angle there, but instead, the opposite happened!

Can anyone help me with this? What exactly am I doing wrong? I'd really appreciate any help I can get here.

Edit-Here's the data:

1) http://cl.ly/2z121M11473p?_ga=1.82079765.2093327149.1426657579

2) http://cl.ly/2G0F2c1V220f?_ga=1.82079765.2093327149.1426657579

Comment: Why don't you just convert to Cartesian using cart2pol (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cart2pol.html).

Comment: The first point on the second data set is further from the y-axis, but it is also much further from the x-axis. Hence the angle from the y-axis is smaller, which is easily seen in the two graphs.

Comment: atan2d already gives the result in degrees, why do you make ".*180/pi"?

Comment: Sorry-that was a mistake in copying my code. I originally didn't have atan2d.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just convert to Cartesian using `cart2pol (X[i,1], X[i,2])` inside your loop?

Reference on cart2pol: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cart2pol.html

Comment: OK, I'm going to go ahead and try this. To find the angle from the positive y axis- would I just subtract the result from 90 (in degrees)?

Comment: Using cart2pol unsurprisingly yields the same answer I got before, so I suppose I was doing it right. I would like to verify though, what's the best method of calculating the angle from the positive y-axis?

Comment: The distances for the first point are bigger in both axes, so it makes sense that the angle is smaller. Your code seems to be correct to me, but your `angles` has a few inefficiencies such as `dot([0,1],[0,1])` (always equal to 1) and the multiplications by the axes can be simplified as well; `angles_2` is much better, but a rountine with `cart2pol` will be easier to read.

Comment: Just to be clear-are you referring to the first point on the first or second graph? Also, I don't mind using cart2pol, but when finding the angle from the positive y axis, I should do 90-cart2pol(X(i,1),X(i,2)) correct?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you wanted degrees and not radians. If you are sure you'll never ever get negative values, `atan2d` is the way to go. I just found a better solution too: `atan2d(X(1:end, 2), X(1:end,1))`. And yes , subtract from 90 to get the angle from y (after using `atan2d`, of course; `cart2pol` returns radians).

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot that it returns the answer in radians. Not a big deal. But I do expect some of my values to be negative (I have another data set that contains points in the second quadrant), how would I deal with that? I honestly thought that atan2 would handle that case just fine. Am I wrong?

Comment: OK, let's say I have a point in the second quadrant. Is the following a correct method of calculating the angle from the point to the positive y-axis:

Y=90-cart2pol(X(:,1),X(:,2))*180/pi

When I did this on the data, I got some negative answers. Is that OK?

Comment: No, I'm afraid. I thought all your points were in the first quadrant... If you want the smallest angle in relation to the y-axis, in any quadrant, positive and in degrees, you should calculate the absolute value of the projection on y-axis, divide it by the distance from zero and then take the arc-cosine; ie, `acos2d (abs (y)/sqrt(x**2 + y**2))`. Another tip: try writing your code with arrays and the dot operator. It will be faster and easier to read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79038/discussion-between-paulo-mendes-and-john-alberto).

Comment: If you want angles in the lower quadrants to be >90º, you need `acos2d(X(2:end,2)./hypot(X(2:end,1), X(2:end,2)))` -- short and sweet in a single line!

Comment: Well, let me clarify. Some of my points are in the first quadrant, and some are in the second. So, I think it's actually OK for some angles to be negative, because that then reflects the fact that the angles are not in the second quadrant. That being the case, do you think what I did before was correct? Also, I dont see why I would have to project the vector onto the y-axis? Can you clarify? Lastly, if by "lower quadrants" you mean the 3rd and 4th, then I don't think I need to worry about that case since I don't have any data there. Thanks a lot for your help though, I've learned a lot already